# UWP - nested navigation tab?

Tags: c#, uwp

I essentially have a UWP app that has a top navigation pane, like in this link here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/navigationview

Now, within that link it also shows something like this:

[image]

This is kind of what I want, but currently, I do not know how I can integrate that with what I have at the moment. In my `ShellPage.xaml`, I have the following layout for my navigation view.

```
    <winui:NavigationView.MenuItems>
        <winui:NavigationViewItem x:Uid="Shell_Main" helpers:NavHelper.NavigateTo="views:MainPage" />
        <winui:NavigationViewItem x:Uid="Shell_Config" Icon="Document" helpers:NavHelper.NavigateTo="views:ConfigPage" />
        <winui:NavigationViewItem x:Uid="Shell_Passengers" Icon="Home" helpers:NavHelper.NavigateTo="views:PassengersPage" />
    </winui:NavigationView.MenuItems>
```

If I want to have a sub-menu where `Passengers` is like the `Collections` example above, with 2 sub-items like `Adults` or `Children`, I do not quite know how to achieve this in XAML. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Never mind! Think I worked it out (sorry for the pointless question!). You have to do something like:

```
       <winui:NavigationViewItem x:Uid="Shell_Passengers" Icon="Document" helpers:NavHelper.NavigateTo="views:PassengersPage">
            <winui:NavigationViewItem.MenuItems>
                <winui:NavigationViewItem x:Uid="Shell_Adults" Icon="Document" helpers:NavHelper.NavigateTo="views:AdultsPage"/>
                <winui:NavigationViewItem x:Uid="Shell_Children" Icon="Document" helpers:NavHelper.NavigateTo="views:ChildrenPage"/>
            </winui:NavigationViewItem.MenuItems>
        </winui:NavigationViewItem>
```

Comment: U said uwp in ur question title but yet here using win ui why ?